# .Net Windows Service not able to access a file

Tags: .net, windows, web-services

I have VB.net windows service and in one of the functions I am using a XML file which is in the same directory of the application.

When I install the service though the service starts it is not finding the xml file. How do I include the XML file in the web service?

If I copy the file to the same folder as the exe and app.config files, it is still not able to find it.

Comment: How is the service trying to 'find' the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like any other kind of application, a Windows Service locates files through a path. If the path is not absolute, then the current directory path is part of the file lookup.

You should make sure you know what your current directory is. Display `System.Environment.CurrentDirectory` and see what the value is.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response john

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
.
.
.
string path =  Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase); 
string fileName = Path.Join(path, "my_xml_file.xml");
```

And then try and open the fileName.

Can it find this?

Answer (score 0):

With Windows services, they are launched through the SvcHost.exe application, so your windows service is based on the context of that application. Try basing the path this way instead:

```
private string GetPath()
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyClass));
    return asm.Location;
}
```

That should get you the full path to the service EXE file, from which you can extract the directory and then combine the XML file name to it.